# C++ 98 array size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm just wondering if there is a way to allocate size of array without specifying it in C++98.

For example, this is code from C++11 that works fine:

```
int main(){
    int array[]={12,3124,126,35742,3,41234,2};
    for (int var: array){
        cout << var << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But can I do it in C++98 or do I have to specify the array size?

```
int main(){
    int array[]={12,3124,126,35742,3,41234,2};
    for (int i=0; i<array.size ; i++){
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try ?

Comment: It doesn't work. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Malcom98: *What* doesn't work??? Declaring an array without specifying its size has been supported in C and C++ since the beginning of times. However, the problems in your code have nothing to do with it. So, what is your question actually about? What is `array.size` supposed to mean?

Comment: AnT, the question was just how to get size of array without mentionin it. Selbie gave a good example below. I get it now.

Comment: @Malcom98: The text of your question explicitly asks how to *allocate* an array without mentioning its size, not how to *get* the size of an already declared array.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I'm just a little lost... Just started a month ago. Must get that basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about that `array.size` thing you reference, but this would suffice.

```
int main()
{

    int array[]={12,3124,126,35742,3,41234,2};

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So this code takes size of whole array and devides it with size of 1 array so we get the wanted number. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no `countof` in C++11. `std::extent` with `decltype` can be used for this purpose though.

Comment: Please add a caveat that this won't work after passing the array to a function. This is a common mistake in this kind of arrays.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Well, it works if you pass the array by reference. It doesn't work if you pass a pointer to the first array element, because a pointer isn't an array.

Answer (score 10):

Sure. You can make a template function which takes an array by reference and deduces the size, then returns that.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

int main(){
    int array[]={12,3124,126,35742,3,41234,2};
    for (size_t i=0; i<array_size(array); i++){
        cout << array[i] << endl;    
    }
}
```

One good thing about this method over using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, is that it will not give you an incorrect answer if `array` is actually a pointer. It will simply fail to compile.

Comment: But you cannot use it in C++03 for struct defined at function scope :-/

Comment: @Jarod42: I'm not sure what you mean. How and why would you use a function which tells you the size of an array for a struct defined at function scope?

Comment: I mean something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a53c855cd10412). I would have the possibility to add data without changing extra code (so solution is to use `sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(*arr)` in that case (or when struct would have meaning, to move it at namespace scope).